# Grouping by items in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, group-by, aggregate, grouping

I have a Python list that looks like this:

`mylist = [[1,apple,orange,banana],[2,apple],[3,banana,grapes]]`

how can i transform it to something like this:

`new_list = [[apple,1,2],[orange,1],[banana,1,3],[grapes,3]`

basically i want to create new list of lists that is grouped by each of the fruits in the original list of lists with the number in the first index

Comment: What have you attempted so far? a few for loops and a `dict` should get you pretty far here.

Comment: (If you'll share your attempt we can help fix it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `defaultdict` to group the indexes per fruit, then concatenate key and values

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist = [[1, "apple", "orange", "banana"], [2, "apple"], [3, "banana", "grapes"]]

result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, *fruits in mylist:
    for fruit in fruits:
        result[fruit].append(idx)
print(result)  # {'apple': [1, 2], 'orange': [1], 'banana': [1, 3], 'grapes': [3]}

result = [[key, *values] for key, values in result.items()]
print(result)  # [['apple', 1, 2], ['orange', 1], ['banana', 1, 3], ['grapes', 3]]
```